# Show that an instance of PCP or MPCP has no solutions

Tags: formal-languages, computability, turing-machines, reductions

I'm studying the Post Correspondence Problem (PCP) and understand the concept, although I have problems with proving how to show that an instance of a PCP or modified PCP has no solutions.

For instance, how could I show that the the instance $\ ((0,11,1), (001,1,11)) $ of an MPCP has no solutions? and what is the thought behind it?

Comment: PCP and MPCP are undecidable so it is unlikely to exist a general proof scheme applicable to every instance. And I don't think your instance of MPCP has no solution: what about 0 0 1=001?

Comment: I think my given instance has no solution, the solution would have to start with the pair (0,001) concatenated with any number of the other pairs (11,1), (0,001) or (1,11). A solution for the PCP would be for example 11 1=1 11. So the pair (11,1) and (1,11) concatenated together. I don't see how your example is a solution?

Comment: I incorrectly recalled the definition of PCP problem, my bad... So no solution of your instance can be proved by counting 0's.

Answer (score 0):

We know that the post correspondence problem and the modified post correspondence problem are undecidable.

It means for both of the problems, we may or may not get the solution depending on the question.

There is no certain procedure or algorithm for the pcp and mpcp problem. So we may not solve the problem in some cases.

Given a question ((0,11,1),(001,1,11)) and we need to find the modified post correspondence problem.

In the modified post correspondence problem, we need to start with the first domino of the question.

While solving the given problem, we will get an infinite loop and we can't get a finite solution.

So we can get

((0,0,1,0,0,1,11,0,0,1,0,0,1,11,.......), (001,001,11,001,001,11,1,001,001,11,001,001,11,1......))

In this,we can see that the dominos are repeating after some steps.

The repeating set of dominos are ((0,0,1,0,0,1,11),(001,001,11,001,001,11,1))

So this lead to the infinite state and can't  be solved.

We can say that, this instance is undecidable.

So modified post correspondence problem is undecidable. Hence there are no solutions for the given instance of modified post correspondence problem.